# How to create a dynamic label colour in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to create a GUI BMI calculator for summer work. 
I want to implement a feature where once you're BMI is calculated, the colour of the label changes depending on your BMI.

My current code reads:

```
self.AnswerlabelVariable = tkinter.StringVar() #Creates a variable used later for changing the label text
Answerlabel = tkinter.Label(self, text=u" ", textvariable=self.AnswerlabelVariable, anchor='w', fg="black",bg="light grey") #Creates a label
Answerlabel.grid(column=1,row=4, sticky='EW') #Defines where the label is and how it will move


...the calculation for the BMI happens...


if float(BMI2)<int(17): #Creates an 'if' statement
    self.MessagelabelVariable.set("You are underweight!") #Changes a label to display a new message.
    self.AnswerlabelVariable.set(fg='black', bg='blue') #Changes a labels colour (WIP WIP WIP)
```

While the label changes it's text, the colour does not change and instead generates an error message;

```
line 56, in OnCalculateButtonClick
self.AnswerlabelVariable.set(fg='black', bg='blue') #Changes a labels colour (WIP WIP WIP)
TypeError: set() got an unexpected keyword argument 'fg'
```

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `config()` method of the label to modify its `fg` and `bg` properties, like this:

```
self.Answerlabel.config(fg='black', bg='blue') #Changes a labels colour
```

Comment: I tried this. When I put it in the code, I got the following error:                        self.AnswerlabelVariable.configure(fg='black', bg='blue') #Changes a labels colour (WIP WIP WIP)
AttributeError: 'StringVar' object has no attribute 'configure'

Comment: Yes, you need to call `configure` on the `Answerlabel` Label. I'll update my answer!
This is because the AnswerlabelVariable isn't responsible for what the Label looks like that you're trying to modify, it only contains the text it should display. So, you need to `configure()` the Label object, not its textvariable.

Comment: I received the following error message when trying the new, edited code: `AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'AnswerLabel'`

Also of note, I tried the code as `self.config.Answerlabel(fg='black', bg='blue')` to get the error `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'MessageLabel'`
And by the way, thankyou for your continued help :)

Comment: You never defined `self.Answerlabel`, you only define `Answerlabel`. So, you also need to do this: `self.Answerlabel = Answerlabel`. It's good to place this directly after the `Answerlabel` definition in your code.

Comment: Thankyou so much :)

Comment: Haha, it's all done. You can probably tell I'm quite new to this ;_;

Answer (score 1):

I've never used the StringVar class but whenever I wanted to change the color (or any parameter) of a Label, I'd just do it directly.

```
Answerlabel['fg'] = 'black'
```

Comment: The `tkinter` module provides the `config()` or `configure()` function to modify the properties of widgets, it looks cleaner than needing a new line for every parameter to be changed.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know :)

Comment: `self.Answerlabel['fg'] = 'black' #Changes a labels colour (WIP WIP WIP)`    Gives me the error `AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'Answerlabel'`